# IE 11 Invalid calling object when lockOrientation called

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code:

```
var lockOrientation = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation;
if (lockOrientation) {
    if (lockOrientation("landscape-primary")) {
        // do something
    }
    else{
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Which is how MDN specifies it should be done:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation

However, in IE11 I get this error:

Invalid calling object

On the line

```
if(lockOrientation("landscape-primary")) {
```

Can someone explain what the problem is here?

Comment: his method is implemented using a prefix (screen.msLockOrientation) in Internet Explorer for Windows 8.1 and Windows RT 8.1. It is not supported on Windows 7.

Comment: I am running windows 8.1 on all machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague has found the solution:

In IE, the method must be called on the screen object, like so:

```
screen.lockOrientationUniversal = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation;
```

and then this works fine.

Seems MDN need to update their site.

Comment: I have submitted an edit to MDN, so hopefully this shouldn't be an issue any more.